# How to display ui timepickr on front using z-index?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, colorbox

Inside colorbox, I am using timepickr. The problem is timepickr
content cut down at edge of colorbox due to **overflow: hidden**.

Here I pasted some code,

// javascript code written by me

```
jQuery(".transportPopup").colorbox({
initialWidth: 150,
initialHeight: 150,
width: 920,
scrolling: false,
transition: "elastic",
opacity: 0.3
}, function() {
   // timepickr on textbox to choose time
   jQuery("#start_time, #end_time").timepickr({updateLive: false, trigger: "focus" });
});
```

The above script crates colorbox popup with html,

```
<div id="colorbox" style="padding-bottom: 42px; padding-right: 42px; display: block; width: 878px; height: 277px; top: 285.5px; left: 44px;">  
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 319px; width: 920px;">  
......  
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 878px; height: 277px;">  
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 878px; overflow: hidden; height: 277px;"><div>  
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">  
        <label class="lblText floatLeft" for="departure_time"><span class="star">*&nbsp;</span>Departure time:&nbsp;</label>                    
        <input type="text" class="inputText w50" readonly="readonly" value="" id="departure_time" name="departure_time">  
        <!-- CODE GENERATED BY TIMPICKR -->  
        <div class="ui-helper-reset ui-timepickr ui-widget" style="left: 309.3px;">  
            ..........  
        </div>          
</div>  
......  
</div>
```

// css of colorbox defined by its author

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

// css of timepickr defined by its author

```
.ui-timepickr {
position:absolute;
width:480px;
top:22px;
display:none;
z-index:99999;
```

}

If I change css of colorbox and make "overflow" property to "visible"
then scrollbar appear on the page and width becomes doubled of the
page.

Answer (score 0):

be sure alle z-index elements have a css `position:` property, otherwise z-index will not work.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Now I found that problem with not z-index but colorbox "overflow" property. If i make overflow "visible" from "hidden" for all colorbox ids, then issue solved, but on overflow page width become double and scrolling appear on the page.

Comment: try to set overflow: auto, does this help?

Comment: well i meant the html and the css and please formatted :-) if you be so kind ;-). adding it to the question (edit^), would be best practice here.

Comment: sorry I am new to stackoverflow so.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Just need to set width of minute div of timepickr.